# MySQL shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

I know this questions has been asked many times here, i searched it a lot and found various answers but still unable to solved my problem.

Apache is running successfully on port 80, but when i try to start mysql, it gives me the following error message.

```
13:36:13  [mysql] Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
13:36:13  [mysql] This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
13:36:13  [mysql] improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
13:36:13  [mysql] Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
13:36:13  [mysql] the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
13:36:13  [mysql] If you need more help, copy and post this
13:36:13  [mysql] entire log window on the forums
```

LogFile

```
140215 13:36:13 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140215 13:36:13 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140215 13:36:13 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
140215 13:36:13 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
140215 13:36:13 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
140215 13:36:13 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Error: space header page consists of zero bytes in data file D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1
140215 13:36:13 InnoDB: Could not open or create data files.
140215 13:36:13 InnoDB: If you tried to add new data files, and it failed here,
140215 13:36:13 InnoDB: you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back
140215 13:36:13 InnoDB: to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created
140215 13:36:13 InnoDB: in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of
140215 13:36:13 InnoDB: zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not
140215 13:36:13 InnoDB: remove old data files which contain your precious data!
140215 13:36:13 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140215 13:36:13 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140215 13:36:13 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140215 13:36:13 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Kindly guide me how to resolve this problem.

Regards,
Aftab

Comment: You may have corrupted your DB file (D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1)? Or you're pointing to a wrong path

Comment: I found this on post that after`ibdata` file deletion it will work fine, thats why i deleted it.

Comment: When you have deleted ibdata1  did you also deleted ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1 from the MySQL directory? If not try doing that to let InnoDB load again and MySQL come up. For precaution you can keep a copy of these files rather than just deleting directly

Comment: I have deleted logfile0, logfile1 with ibdata1. Now its not giving me any error message, and showing databases name in phpmyadmin, but when i click on any table name,it says 'abc table is empty'. Kindly tell me why its noyt showing table data.

Comment: Let me guess. Because your table data were in ibdata1 which you've deleted?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look here :
https://superuser.com/questions/653953/cant-start-mysql-xampp-after-installing-on-external-drive

Hope you did a copy of your file before deleting them ?

Comment: I have deleted logfile0, logfile1 with ibdata1. Now its not giving me any error message, and showing databases name in phpmyadmin, but when i click on any table name,it says 'abc table is empty'. Kindly tell me why its noyt showing table data.

Comment: Well if you deleted the ibdata file (which contain the data), it's quite logical you won't see any no ?

Comment: ibdata is back again, but data is not in the tables except cdcol database.

Comment: It may have recovered some old data, but for the missing one I'm afraid you'll have to put them back yourself

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error, and managed to solve it with this:

go to Xampp/mysql/bin/my.ini

add the following line:

```
innodb_force_recovery = 1
```

(I think anything > 0 works here, also... it might be handy to make a backup of the file just to be on the safe side.)

You should now be able to successfully start your mySQL service.

Comment: The problem is solved, but now i am getting empty database. When i click on any table name, it says table is empty.

Comment: That probably happened because you messed with your ibdata1 file. Your  tables get lost if you do that :c